# Is There a Way to Limit the Number of Consumers on a RabbitMQ Queue?

Tags: rabbitmq

I've got a RabbitMQ setup with lots of queues. Due to the nature of the data in each queue, it has to be processed in strict order, so we can only permit a single consumer on each queue. This isn't a problem as such, but we do run the risk of accidentally starting a second consumer on a queue, which would be a bad thing. There's lots of queues and lots of app servers and it would just take a small typo for us to end up in this situartion.

Before I spend time changing the software to effectively "lock" a queue (storing that lock in a DB or something), is there anything in RabbitMQ that can limit the number of consumers a queue can have? If so, I can limit my queues to just one consumer and my risk of multiple consumers goes away.

Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`exclusive`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume.exclusive) flag in [`consume`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.consume) method serves this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. And pretty obvious now I actually look at the "consume" method!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `sprig framework` you can use the tag `exclusive=true`in the tag rabbit listener `@RabbitListener`. So with you are able to restrict the queue to one consumer.

`@RabbitListener(queues = "${queue.name}", exclusive = true)`

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party, but for whoever might encounter this - if you need exactly one active consumer, you can use the new feature (since 3.8) - https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#single-active-consumer

**Single Active Consumer**

> Single active consumer allows to have only one consumer at a time
> consuming from a queue and to fail over to another registered consumer
> in case the active one is cancelled or dies.